# Changed a path that is used by System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo() and I am now getting a parsing error

Tags: c#, .net, windows, parsing, f#

We have automated tests running nightly on our product, and recently changed from VS2015 to VS2017 to build both our automated tests, and our software under test. Since all the tools (VsDevCmd.bat, mstest.exe, etc) are located in a different path in VS2017, I needed to change those paths in our test runner's config files. So, for example, for VsDevCmd.bat we went from:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat
```

to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat
```

Now the function that we use to run a test category looks like follows:

```
let private runTestsWithoutPublishing (testCategory,testContainers:String[],resultFilePath,testSettingPath) = ccr {    
let stc =
    testContainers
    |>Array.map (fun tc -> sprintf "/testcontainer:\"%s\"" tc)
let tcontainers = String.Join(" ", stc)

let t1 =  
    sprintf "mstest.exe %s /category:\"%s\" /resultsfile:\"%s\" /testsettings:\"%s\""  
        tcontainers testCategory resultFilePath testSettingPath

let psi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe","/k \""+VSDCPath+"\"") 
psi.UseShellExecute <- false
psi.RedirectStandardOutput <- true
psi.RedirectStandardError <- true
psi.RedirectStandardInput <- true
psi.CreateNoWindow <- false        
let p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi) 
let output = new System.Text.StringBuilder()
let error = new System.Text.StringBuilder()
p.OutputDataReceived.Add(fun args -> 
    output.Append(args.Data)|> ignore
    output.Append("\r\n")|> ignore)
p.ErrorDataReceived.Add(fun args -> error.Append(args.Data) |> ignore)
p.BeginErrorReadLine()
p.BeginOutputReadLine()
p.StandardInput.WriteLine t1
p.StandardInput.WriteLine "Exit"
p.WaitForExit()
return { exitCode = p.ExitCode; stdout = output.ToString(); stderr = error.ToString() }

}
```

Where `VSDCPath` is one of the two paths mentioned above.

The problem I am seeing since the path change mentioned above is that I am now seeing the following error when running this code:

```
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.'mstest.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
```

So the parsing seems to have broken since I changed the path, and I don't understand why since `VSDCPath` is surrounded by double quotes `\"`. Also, both paths have spaces in them, but only the first one works with the above code.

Am I missing something?

Comment: where do you define `VSDCPath` in the script? You should add that path into double quotes. In other words, wherever you define `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat` it should be in double quotes. `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"` the reason is tha tyour `cmd /k` command already grabs the first set of double quotes.

Comment: If the same code works with one path but doesn't work with another path, there's a decent chance that the error isn't actually coming from your code at all. Could you show us (or add to a gist somewhere) the contents of the two `VsDevCmd.bat` files, one from Visual Studio 11.0 and the other from Visual Studio 2017? I've seen enough other bugs in VS 2017 that it wouldn't surprise me too much if there was an error in that batch file where someone forgot to quote a parameter. It's not necessarily the cause, but it's something I can't rule out until I see those batch files.

Comment: ... Or it could just be that `cmd /k` is eating the first set of double quotes and you need a *second* set, as Gerhard Barnard just said. That's also a possibility.